# ¿Cómo puedo centrar en el medio de una tarjeta un icono sin tener que modificar su padding-top?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive, card

Estoy utilizando una tarjeta responsive de Bootstrap y sin modificar nada queda el ícono en el margen superior de la tarjeta. Al momento de probar su desempeño responsive funciona bien ya qué el ícono se centra pero si vuelvo al tamaño original de la pantalla este mismo vuelve a la parte superior de arriba.

Una solución fue modificarle el `padding-top` como muestro en el ejemplo de la tarjeta 2 en la cual se puede observar que ahí si queda centra en el medio pero ahora el problema es que al probarla responsivamente queda con ese `padding` y se ve estéticamente mal por el borde superior que genera bastante espacio entre el icono.

¿Se puede solucionar que quede centrado y en el medio sin que se vea mal desde móvil y desde pc?

- La tarjeta uno es la original pero en **pc** se ve el icono arriba y en **móvil** se ve centrado.
- La tarjeta dos se ve centrado pero colocando el `padding` al icono en **pc** se ve bien pero en **móvil** no.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleabout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color: #a9b67b;">





  <div style="background-color: #232d35; margin-top: 1.3%; margin-bottom: 1.2%; padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%;">
    <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">


      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;">
            <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff; margin-top: -10%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">Horarios de atención</h5>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 7%; font-size: 85%;">Lunes a Viernes
              </p>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 22:00hs
              </p><br>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -6.5%; font-size: 85%;">Sábado, Domingo y Feriados</p>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 18:00hs
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>




      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center; padding-top: 6.7%;">
            <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff; margin-top: -10%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">Horarios de atención</h5>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 7%; font-size: 85%;">Lunes a Viernes
              </p>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 22:00hs
              </p><br>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -6.5%; font-size: 85%;">Sábado, Domingo y Feriados</p>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 18:00hs
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

- Quitamos el `padding-top: 6.7%;` de tu elemento quien encierra al ícono del reloj, ya que no sería la manera correcta para centrar el contenido de adentro (tu ícono), esto lo hago a ambos elementos (de los 2 cards):

  ```
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;"> <!-- quito el padding-top: 6.7%; -->
    <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff; margin-top: -10%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></i>
  </div>
  ```
- Ponemos las siguientes clases de Bootstrap para indicar que su contenido de adentro (tu ícono) sea flexible, esté alineado al centro y justificado al centro de su elemento:

  ```
  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;">
    <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff; margin-top: -10%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></i>
  </div>
  ```
- Y por último, quitamos los márgenes que le habías dado al ícono, ya que esto afectaría a las clases de Bootstrap y haría que el ícono se salga de su contenedor:

  ```
  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;">
    <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff;"></i> <!-- quito el "margin-top: -10%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" -->
  </div>
  ```

Código final:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleabout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #a9b67b;">
    <div style="background-color: #232d35; margin-top: 1.3%; margin-bottom: 1.2%; padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%;">
      <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;">
              <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">Horarios de atención</h5>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 7%; font-size: 85%;">Lunes a Viernes
                </p>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 22:00hs
                </p><br>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -6.5%; font-size: 85%;">Sábado, Domingo y Feriados</p>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 18:00hs
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #248d8d; border-radius: 3%; text-align: center;">
              <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 400%; color: #ffffff;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">Horarios de atención</h5>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 7%; font-size: 85%;">Lunes a Viernes
                </p>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 22:00hs
                </p><br>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -6.5%; font-size: 85%;">Sábado, Domingo y Feriados</p>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -3%; color: #113349;">08:00hs a 18:00hs
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Genial Cris, ahí lo probé y quedó perfecto. Gracias!!

Comment: No hay de que, por cierto, evita tener tus estilos en tu HTML, se vería mejor tenerlo en tu CSS, a mi opinión :-)